# update Widget Non periodiccally

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver

I have a widget that contains a `TextView` that i want update only when `Onreceive()`{this receiver is not the one implemented for widget} method is invoked. I dont want to update the widget periodically but only when my `Onreceive()` is invoked.

**Recver.java**

```
public class Recver extends BroadcastReceiver {



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Widgetd.updatewid(context);

            }
    }

    }}
```

**Widgetd.java**

```
public class Widgetd extends AppWidgetProvider {


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }
    static void updatewid(Context context){

        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widgetlay);
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetUpdateTv, "1");



    }

}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="delete.detailduplicate"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="delete.detailduplicate.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Newmain"></activity>
        <receiver android:name="Recver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="9999999">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="Widgetd">
            <intent-filter >
                <action 
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widgetsetter" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**widgetsetter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widgetlay"
    android:minHeight="300dp"
    android:minWidth="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `updatePeriodMillis = "0"`:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_initial_layout"
android:minHeight="40dp"
android:minWidth="40dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen" 
android:previewImage="@drawable/my_app_logo"/>
```

add the intent which should trigger the update in the AndroidManifest (here for example WIFI_STATE_CHANGED):

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and in app widget code call your `updateWidget` method:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() " + intent.getAction());
            super.onReceive(context, intent);

            if (intent != null)
            {
                    if (WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction()))
                    {
                            updateWidgets(context);
                    }
            ...
            }
     }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
         Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate()");
         updateWidgets(context);
    }


    private void updateWidgets(Context context)
    {
        AppWidgetManager m = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        if (m != null)
        {
            int[] appWidgetIds = 
                  m.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, getClass()));
            if ((appWidgetIds != null) && (appWidgetIds.length > 0))
            {
                 final RemoteViews updateViews = 
                    new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.mywidget_layout);
                    ...
                    m.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, updateViews);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: doesnt it requires to register the class that extends AppWidgetProvider to register as receiver in manifest

Comment: if i didn't follow the conventional method of registering receiver the  widget doesn't creates .As u mentioned i created a method in  class that extends AppWidgetProvider and called it from where Onreceive() method but it doesn't updates the widget.

Comment: Ok, you should remove your `Recver` and add a `OnReceive` method to `Widgetd.java` like I described: `intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")`. Also move the intent filter for `SMS_RECEIVED` to `Widgetd`in manifest.xml. In the logcat you should see all received messages then.

Comment: @ j.holetzeck sir, all i want is to raise the value of the textview in the widget as a sms is received and perform some other stuff in OnReceive() method of Recver. So sholud i delete the Recver class and tranfer the OnReceive() code to OnReceive in Widgetd.java

Comment: As an app widget is just a BroadcastReceiver anyway I think this would be a good approach.

Comment: <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" /> without this action the widget is not created

Comment: You can add more than one action: `<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>`

Comment: thanks to u everything is working, only i am not able to figure out how to call onupdate() from onreceive() as it requires three parameters onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
   int[] appWidgetIds)

Comment: @dreamer1989 you are not supposed to call onUpdate() from onReceive() by yourself. It is done automatically by the framework in `onReceive()` when the `AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE` intent has been broadcast by the system. This happens automatically when you drag a new widget to the home screen. You can see the relevant code here http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.java#57.